# Laravel 5 Naming Conventions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am bit confused with Laravel conventions as I am new to this framework. I am following Jeffrey Way Laracasts videos he uses **Plural** for Controller names.

E.g.: **PagesController, Cards Controller, PostsController**

But if I refer official documentations of [Laravel > Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers) and [Laravel > Tutorials > Quick Start > Intermediate Task List](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart-intermediate#the-task-controller) it uses **Singular** names.

E.g.: **PhotoController, TaskController**

Can anybody please list down the official coding conventions for following entities?

Tables: **posts, comments, post_comments** or **Post, Comment, PostComment**

Columns: **id, post_id, comment_id** or **id, postId, commentId**

Controllers: **PagesController, Cards Controller, PostsController** or **PhotoController, TaskController**

Models: **Pages, Cards, Posts** or **Page, Card, Post**

Comment: I would agree with both below apart from naming controllers. I've seen people use both singular and plural for controllers and quite honestly it's whichever makes more sense to you. Just be consistent with whichever one you go with.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Tables:** posts, comments, comment_post

**Columns:** id, post_id, comment_id

**Controllers:** PhotoController, TaskController

**Models:** Page, Card, Post

For more details check out my [Laravel naming conventions](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions) table.

Comment: isn't it post_comments? I think not post_comment

Comment: No, it's actually should be `comment_post` which is derived from foreign key names in the alphabetical order.

Comment: It is confusing, if the database tables naming convention is snake case plurals why it is comment_post? It should be post_comments because 1 post can have many comments. Anyway according to documentation if I want I can use $table = 'post_comments'; code snippet to change default table name to my own one under model class.

Comment: @YohanHirimuthugoda you're talking about pivot table, usually, those do not have their own model. But you can define custom pivot table name when defining `belongsToMany()` relationship. I wouldn't recommend you to do that, though. It's always better to follow conventions to create readable and maintainable apps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. I will follow conventions as much as I can, as suggested by you. Another small thing I need to clarify; When I need to group particular controller's views, is it plural or singular folder names? E.g.: posts or post

Comment: What about model names that contain abbreviations. E.g `ERC20`.

Comment: Just to clarify if anyone is confused (as I was). When defining a model for a pivot table, the class `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot` can be used, which fixes assuming plural table names for models.

Answer (score 6):

Remember that "conventions" are just conventions and you could do whatever you want just be constant, however it's better follow the documentation:

1. [**Table name**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations): plural and `_` to separate words (users, tags, ...)
2. [**Columns name**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations): singular and `_` to separate words (user, tag, ...)
3. [**Models**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent): singular with first letter capitalized and capitalization to separate words (User, Tag, ...)
4. [**Controllers**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers): singular with capitalized first letter and capitalization to separate words followed by "Controller" (UserController, TagController, ...)

Comment: Controller name shouldn't rely on a model name. In a real app there are a lot of controllers that do not have "it's own model" and controllers that use many models.

Comment: Yes, if a controller is associate with a model it's better associate them but if you can't just singular + "Controller" (TagController, UserController, ...)

Comment: This is how to name a `model` with a name consists of multiple words: `UserMetaKey`. A model with that name expects a table with the name `user_meta_keys` to deal with.

Comment: what about in the blade file, name="modelname"

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm from old school (*coding since 1984 on computers, though having evolved with PHP and js/ECMAScript since their first version*), but the good old Merise rule "never use plural" had strong and good resasons to be respected.
What a pity Eloquent forces us to use table name in plural.

PSR-2 or PSR-1 doesn't indicate anything about plural or singular, but for simplicity sake, I heavily recommend to always use singular, excepte where the "system" needs it (as Eloquent does). In that case, don't mix plural and singular. On the datatables used by laravel, we use table names in plural. That's a singularity (compared to the other developments already made or with which we communicate), but all the tables are in plural on that part.

And NEVER make a typo when naming something (example: 'personnal' i.o. 'personal', etc.). Doublecheck first. Orthograph rules.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with this. I NEVER want to have to remember various rules for what is pluralized and what is not. EVERYTHING is singular, no exceptions.

Comment: I agree too. It would be great if you could define your preferences for this type of thing in a config file that Laravel reads. Then you could certainly base your names on their recommendations, but be free to override when things like Eloquent break the paradigm.