# Laravel naming convention for blade files

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I know that naming conventions in Laravel is covered in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655535/laravel-5-naming-conventions), but blade files are not covered there. I read several blogs and forums and they all offer different approach so I want to ask here:

My controller method is **AdminController@listPropertyTypes** - which lists and manages the property types..

One blog suggests:

```
/resources/views/admin/property/types.blade.php
```

Another blogs suggest underscore or no space:

```
/resources/views/admin/property_types.blade.php
/resources/views/admin/propertytypes.blade.php
```

I would personally named this way since it is a view:

```
/resources/views/admin/property-types.blade.php
```

Is there a best practice or PSR rule for this?

Comment: Best practice? I don't believe so, and PSR rule, these are general rules for PHP standards, Blade is a Laravel specific, so no. As long as you are consistent across your codebase and you/your team are all happy with the convention you decide to use then do whatever you like.

Comment: If you are asking about best practices, then one suggestion would be to strictly use CRUD controllers; AdminController@listPropertyTypes is not CRUD. AdminPropertyTypesController@index is more "best practice".

Comment: I use this convetions https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### EDIT: Laravel community mostly use kebab-case or camelCase

ie `views/admin/property-types.blade.php` or `views/admin/propertyTypes.blade.php`

Laravel's creator seems to use kebab-case, but [Spatie recommends camelCase](https://spatie.be/guidelines/laravel-php#content-views).

As [@MrEduar explained it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61811471/1077650), there is no strict convention.

NB: https://www.laravelbestpractices.com website is abandonned and not affiliated with Laravel.

---

#### OLD: Initial answer

I came across [Laravel Best Practices](https://www.laravelbestpractices.com/#views).

**Laravel : Best Practices** aims to put together all the resources and best practices in using the Laravel Framework. Last Updated: 2020-05-07 12:26:48

**Views**

You SHOULD use **snake_case** as file name of your Blade templates

Good

```
show_filtered.blade.php
```

Bad

```
showFiltered.blade.php
show-filtered.blade.php
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not that comfortable with this naming convention but I'll go this way.

Comment: Hm Taylor himself uses kebab-case like in https://github.com/illuminate/pagination/tree/master/resources/views

Comment: Basically, I usually go for kebab-case for naming my routes as well as the view. It works out pretty well.

Comment: https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices suggests kebab case naming

Comment: https://www.laravelbestpractices.com/#views is now an abandonned website. I agree with @shock_gone_wild and go with kebab-case

Answer (score 4):

For blade file names, there is no convention as such. But as @James says in his commentary, and I quote

> If you are asking about best practices, then one suggestion would be
> to strictly use CRUD controllers; AdminController@listPropertyTypes is
> not CRUD. AdminPropertyTypesController@index is more "best practice".

And in this case the best way would be `/resources/views/admin/property/types.blade.php`.

You can read more about this in Laracon 2017 or in [Adam Watham's github repository](https://github.com/adamwathan/laracon2017/pull/1) where he explains it further.

If you are not happy with this result I suggest you also use CamelCase According to the [Spatie Guidelines](https://spatie.be/guidelines/laravel-php#content-views)

```
resources/
  views/
    openSource.blade.php
```

So, in the controller

```
class OpenSourceController
{
    public function index() {
        return view('openSource');
    }
}
```

**Instead of looking at unreliable blogs, be guided by the great minds of the Laravel community.**

Comment: Fixed Spatie broken URL (again); and +1 for the "unreliable blogs" warning!

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on this post because I have a Controller method that returns dynamic view that matches the request path. I've long used the snake_case for my blade files but we all know that route paths could be hyphenated (dashed), and I want them to match the blade files.

Now I'm asking myself if it's okay to ditch the snake_case and dash my-blade files, or should I stick with mr snake and somehow convert the route path to match.

Note. I've tried the dashed-version and things look okay. But I was pricked to check convention, here I am.